# Trying to write my first "global" function for my nodejs controllers

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got this function that I use in almost all my nodejs controllers.

The function is in the file ../global/daysBetween.js

```
"use strict";
module.exports.daysBetween = (date1, date2) => {
    var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    var date1_ms = date1.getTime()
    var date2_ms = date2.getTime()
    var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms)
    return Math.round(difference_ms/ONE_DAY)
}
```

First I thought about putting it into `global` but many examples here on stackoverflow says thats a bad idea.

So I tried to include it into the controllers that use it:

```
"use strict";
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var daysBetween = require('../global/daysBetween');
exports.newBooking = function(req, callback) {
    console.log("Days Between: " + daysBetween(bookingRecord.checkin,bookingRecord.checkout));
}
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: daysBetween is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

And Should I include it in each controller with require?  Or would it be better to declare it on the global scope?

This is what is being exported:

```
console.log(require('../global/daysBetween'));
return;

{ daysBetween: [Function] }
```

Comment: `console.log(require('../global/daysBetween'));` see, and post, what is being exported.

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy I updated the question with `{ daysBetween: [Function] }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're exporting this:

```
{
    daysBetween:function...
}
```

Try:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = (date1, date2) => {
    var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    var date1_ms = date1.getTime()
    var date2_ms = date2.getTime()
    var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms)
    return Math.round(difference_ms/ONE_DAY)
}
```

Remove the daysBetween property.

exports is an object. When you add `.someField`, you're adding a property into this object; if you want to export only one function you have to replace the exports object with your own function.

```
module.exports = ()=>{ return 'exports is now a function'};

module.exports.func = ()=>{ return 'exports is an object with the function "func"'};
```

[Tutorial on module.exports](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports)

Comment: Thanks Cheloide - you were right. Everything works now and I can finally write some nice "global" functions.  Side question:  When would you attach functions to the global scope `global.myFunction()` or would you totally avoid that?

Comment: I have never done that, I haven't had the need to, but I usually avoid using global/static functions.

Comment: @torbenrudgaard Forget about the `global` way, and go forward using `require()` where is needed. The best path you can follow is creating a real module for it, and publish it on npm. Check: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=difference+days